# Merge argument but within one dataset. How to condense dataframe if client changed names?

Tags: r

How would I apply a merge function of rows already loaded in one frame? As seen below, Client EE switched names to TE beginning 2013. I want to collapse the set into one, so taking EE 2011 and 2012 data then inserting it in 2013 and 2014 of TE (getting rid of EE in the process). I also have other data in the set like client FE which I don't want manipulated in the process but kept in the final data frame.

Data:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/smmlY.jpg

```
structure(list(ClientID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Client = c("EE", "EE", "EE", 
"EE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "EE", "EE", "EE", "EE", "TE", "TE", 
"TE", "TE", "FE"), ItemCode = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 15L), Item = c("plastic", 
"plastic", "plastic", "plastic", "plastic", "plastic", "plastic", 
"plastic", " metal", " metal", " metal", " metal", " metal", 
" metal", " metal", " metal", "plastic"), DomainCode = c(112L, 
113L, 114L, 115L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 
112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 112L), Domain = c("Sector1", "Sector2", 
"Sector3", "Sector4", "Sector1", "Sector2", "Sector3", "Sector4", 
"Sector1", "Sector2", "Sector3", "Sector4", "Sector1", "Sector2", 
"Sector3", "Sector4", "Sector1"), Unit = c("kg", "kg", "kg", 
"kg", "kg", "kg", "kg", "kg", "kg", "kg", "kg", "kg", "kg", "kg", 
"kg", "kg", "kg"), X2011 = c(3L, 11L, 3L, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
9L, 6L, 5L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L), X2012 = c(4L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 7L, 10L, 12L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L), X2013 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 8L, 4L, 9L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 12L, 6L, 
6L), X2014 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
12L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 8L)), .Names = c("ClientID", "Client", "ItemCode", 
"Item", "DomainCode", "Domain", "Unit", "X2011", "X2012", "X2013", 
"X2014"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

final results expected

```
structure(list(ClientID = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L
), Client = c("TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", 
"FE"), ItemCode = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 15L
), Item = c("plastic", "plastic", "plastic", "plastic", " metal", 
" metal", " metal", " metal", "plastic"), DomainCode = c(112L, 
113L, 114L, 115L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 112L), Domain = c("Sector1", 
"Sector2", "Sector3", "Sector4", "Sector1", "Sector2", "Sector3", 
"Sector4", "Sector1"), Unit = c("kg", "kg", "kg", "kg", "kg", 
"kg", "kg", "kg", "kg"), X2011 = c(9L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 
2L, 9L, 5L), X2012 = c(7L, 12L, 5L, 2L, 12L, 9L, 8L, 12L, 7L), 
    X2013 = c(9L, 11L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 6L), X2014 = c(3L, 
    8L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L)), .Names = c("ClientID", 
"Client", "ItemCode", "Item", "DomainCode", "Domain", "Unit", 
"X2011", "X2012", "X2013", "X2014"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the `dput`.  Do you want to replace the `NA` rows in 2011` and `2012` columns with the values in `2013` `2014`?

Comment: I want to move 2011 and 2012 to NA in updated client name, so TE. Then rows which had 2011 and 2012 data to be deleted, since it was moved to 2013 and 2014.

Comment: The values in the expected output for the year columns is different from the one in the input.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that. This data sample was created via Excel random gen--and it updated when I manipulated it. Hopefully that didn't cause confusion.

Comment: correct, specifically (2, TE, 15, plastic, 112, Sector1, kg, 3, 4, 8, 2) then deleting row one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
indx <- dat$Client =='TE'
indx1 <- dat$Client=='EE'
dat1 <- dat[dat$Client %in% c('TE', 'FE'),]
dat1[dat1$Client=='TE',c('X2011', 'X2012')] <-  Map(function(x,y) replace(x,
       is.na(x), na.omit(y)), dat1[indx, c("X2011", "X2012")],
                   dat[indx1,c("X2011", "X2012")])
```